# POST http://localhost:3000/users 500 (Internal Server Error) - Unable to post data to my .json file

Tags: html, post, fetch-api

I am trying to post the records from my html user registration form to my .json db file but I keep getting the error : POST http://localhost:3000/users 500 (Internal Server Error) . My json server is running on my local machine.

My JS Code

```
let form = document.querySelector(".form");
  form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let formData = new FormData(form);
    let data = Object.fromEntries(formData);
    jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

    fetch("http://localhost:3000/users", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: jsonData,
    })
  }
```

Please help identify where my code has an issue...

Comment: Things looks good in above code, better create a code snippet to understand your query better

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Vishal, yes. Seems the code is okay. I converted my db.json file to a public API using retool api-generator and posting works okay after the data is submitted without having to change the code.